# What does "equals to negative 1" mean in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand a piece of code that searches for a string inside a text file. What does it mean? Is it like "False"?

```
if x.find('string1') != -1:                   
    if x.find('string2') == -1 and x.find('string3') == -1:                                         
        return file
        break
```

Comment: Your downvotes shout 'RTFM', which I refer you to here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html which says "Return the lowest index in s where the substring sub is found such that sub is wholly contained in s[start:end]. **Return -1 on failure** "

Comment: @MartinCowie: and you have found the wrong documentation, in that it describes a deprecated function in the `string` module, while the code in the question uses the `str.find()` method (which replaces the deprecated function). The description of the behaviour might be correct, but watch out for subtleties like that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [`str.find()` method documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.find):

> Return -1 if *sub* is not found.

So the first `if` condition tests if `string1` is found in `x`; if it is, a value *other* than `-1` would be returned. The second `if` condition tests if two strings are *not* present in `x` (because only then `-1` is returned for both `str.find()` calls).

It really should use a membership test (the `in` operator) instead:

```
if 'string1' in x and 'string2' not in x and 'string3' not in x: 
    return file
```

The `break` after the `return` is never reached.